# ActiveMQ: Set priority for message is not working

Tags: c#, .net, activemq-classic, nms

I have problems setting message priorities via nms. The messages are sent to the queue everything is ok but the priority is ignored.

I use the following code:

```
message.NMSPriority = MsgPriority.High;
```

Regardless what value I set for message priority, using the ActiveMQ browser I can see that the priority is always set to 4.

I also tried to add some raw headers like:

```
message.Properties["priority"] = 2;
message.Properties["PRIORITY"] = 5;
message.Properties["NMSPriority"] = 7;
message.Properties["JMSPriority "] = 9;
```

But it doesn't help.

I also have added the attribute

```
prioritizedMessages="true"
```

to the activemq.xml file. And I can send a message with priority manually via the ActiveMQ browser.

So where is the problem? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message priority is always set by the producer that sends the Message.  The setter on the class will only allow you to change the value after you've received a message and is usually only used for unit testing or converting Messages between providers.  To set Message priority on a per message basis have a look at the different send methods in the MessageProducer interface.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer solved my problem! But it is interesting that I can set the message properties via the setter class and other things too, but not the priority.

Comment: You can refer to the JMS API documentation on things like this, the various setters are tagged to indicate which one's are not applicable to sent Messages